# "code ." is not working in on the command line for Visual Studio Code on window 10

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, command

although i add enviroment variable but it seem doesn't work

Added variable:
[image]

The error i got:
[image]
, the window of vscode doesn't show when i use "code .".
i tried to add path again but it seem like not working

The path of "code" command:
[image]

Comment: are you trying to open the terminal?

Comment: i'm trying to open vscode from terminal